# Trazer um ID recem adicionado para colocar em uma textbox c# windows form

Tags: c#, textbox, linq-to-sql, text

Solicito uma ajuda para fazer o seguinte, faço um insert via procedure apos salvar quero preencher o textbox com o id criado para eu conseguir usar-lo para associar ao meus item 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só preciso que o codigo do pedido entre no textbox.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda.
Evento do botão novo

```
 private void btnNovoPedido_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            int codigoCli = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodCliente.Text);
            DateTime dtIni = DateTime.Now;
            int idCliente = int.Parse(txtCodCliente.Text);
            cc.pInserirPedido(0, dtIni, null, idCliente); //procedure para criar pedido
            MessageBox.Show("Pedido gerado" );


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

ALTER PROC [dbo].[pInserirPedido]
@valorTotal decimal(8,2),
@dtEntrada datetime,
@dtSaida datetime,
@idCliente int
as
 
insert into TB_PEDIDOS(VAL_PEDIDO,
 HOR_PEDIDO_ENTRADA,HOR_PEDIDO_SAIDA,ID_CLIENTE)
values(@valorTotal, @dtEntrada, @dtSaida, @idCliente) 
IF @@ERROR<>0
  -- 
SELECT -1
 vai retornar -1 caso haja erro 
    ELSE
        SELECT MAX(ID_PEDIDO) as 'PEDIDO ATUAL' FROM TB_PEDIDOS
        GO
 o ultimo ID adicionado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

entao ainda não sei como pega o valor exibido no sql e jogar no campo 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cadê o código do insert ? Cadê o código do botão?

Comment: Adicionei o evento do botao novo porem não adicionei o de colocar no textbox porque não sei como fazer talusando IQueryable mais não sei usar só consigo usar se o ID estiver em um grid ai então recupero o valor igual aqui: int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dgvCliente.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                txtCodigo.Text = codigo.ToString();   exemplo de um valor que peguei do grid .

Comment: cc.pInserirPedido retorna algum valor?

Comment: Não só insere mesmo um novo pedido então depois que vou adicionar itens ao pedido por outra proc mais pra isso preciso receber o id do pedido criado

Comment: coloque o código do `cc.pInserirPedido`

Comment: Coloquei a proc lá na pergunta

Comment: O banco é SQL Server? Se for, vc chegou a pensar em usar `SELECT @@Identity` como retorno da PROC? Outra coisa, qual é o tipo da variável `cc`?

Comment: Ola Fernando  CC é a a instancia da classe ConexaoClienteDataContext ela que uso para fazer qualquer coisa no banco estou usando LINQ to SQL classes . Não tentei não seria eu usaria após a inserir ? como posso usar ela se de estou pesquisando já sobre

Comment: Fiz o que você orientou na proc ela está trazendo a ultimo id adicionado mais só estou coseguindo ver no sql server o retorno do select mais para implementar no c# ainda não porque não sei como pegar o retorno desse select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá achei a solução de maneira mais simples do que já imaginei segue solução

```
 private void btnNovoPedido_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pInserirPedidoResult con = new pInserirPedidoResult();

        try
        {
            int codigoCli = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodCliente.Text);
            DateTime dtIni = DateTime.Now;
            int idCliente = int.Parse(txtCodCliente.Text);
            cc.pInserirPedido(0, dtIni, null, idCliente);
            MessageBox.Show("Pedido gerado");
            txtIDPedido.Text = cc.TB_PEDIDOs.Max(x => x.ID_PEDIDO).ToString(); <--- // AQUI A SOLUÇÃO !!! Achei já perdendo a esperança ufa   traz o id recem criado                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro:" + ex.Message);
        }

             }
```

fonte: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/max-com-linq/439548